# Find replace "./." in awk

Tags: awk

I am very new to using linux and I am trying to find/replace some of the text in my file.

I have successfully been able to find and replace "0/0" using gsub:

`awk '{gsub(/0\/0/,"0")};  1'     filename`

However, if I try to replace "./." using the same idea

`awk '{gsub(/\.\/\./,"U")};  1'     filename`

the output is truncated and stops at the location of the first "./." in the file.  I know that "." is a special wildcard character, but I thought that having the "\" in front of it would neutralize it.  I have searched but have been unable to find an explanation why the formula I used would truncate the file.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: `awk` is not the best tool for such operation. I propose to use `sed` instead, if you are allowed to make your own choice.

Comment: If I do `echo "abc./.def" | awk 'gsub(/\.\/\./,"U")'` it works as expected.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @melpomene do you know you can also say `[mcve]` --> [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the basic outline of an `awk` is:

```
awk 'pattern { action }'
```

The most common patterns are regexes or tests against line counts:

```
awk '/FOO/ { do_something_with_a_line_with_FOO_in_it }'
awk 'FNR==10'
```

The last one has no action so the default is to print the line.

But functions that return a value are also useable as patterns. `gsub` is a function and returns the number of substitutions.

So given:

```
$ echo "$txt"
abc./.def line 1
ghk/lmn won't get printed
abc./.def     abc./.def   printed
```

To print only lines that have a successful substitution you can do:

```
$ echo "$txt" | awk 'gsub(/\.\/\./,"U")'
abcUdef line 1
abcUdef     abcUdef   printed
```

You do not need to put `gsub` into an action block since you want to run it on every line and the return tells you something about what happened. The lines that successfully are matched are printed since `gsub` returns the number of substitutions.

If you want every line printed regardless if there is a match:

```
$ echo "$txt" | awk 'gsub(/\.\/\./,"U") || 1'
abcUdef line 1
ghk/lmn won't get printed
abcUdef     abcUdef   printed
```

Or, you can use the function as an action with an empty pattern and then a `1` with an empty action:

```
$ echo "$txt" | awk '{gsub(/\.\/\./,"U")} 1'
abcUdef line 1
ghk/lmn won't get printed
abcUdef     abcUdef   printed
```

In either case, `1` as a pattern with no action prints the line regardless if there is a match and the `gsub` makes the substitution if any.

The second `awk` is what you have. Why it is not working on your input data is probably related to you input data.

Answer (score 1):

Your awk script is fine, your input contains control-Ms, probably from being created by a Windows program. You can see them with `cat -v file` and use `dos2unix` or similar to remove them.